# set relationship in models without DB Context File

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, model-view-controller

I am developing an app where i am using MVC in Presentation layer so I have to define model classes  in it.....and because of that I want relationship in that models.

How can we define relationship in model without Dbcontext class file.

Comment: As per Code first approach i can solve this issue but don't want to create Db-context file....

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense, if you want help you're going to have to try harder to explain your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't exactly understand what you are asking for, but I will take a shot.

EF creates relationships in models by having a reference to the related model(s).

Say you have models Cart and Item. A Cart can contain many Items, and any one Item can only belong to one Cart. This would be a one-to-many relationship.

```
public class Cart
{
    public int CartId {get;set;}
    //other properties

    public List<Item> Items {get;set;}
}

public class Item
{
   public int ItemId {get;set;}
   // other properties

   public Cart Cart {get;set;}
}
```

So from your Cart class you can fetch any Items it contains, and from any of those Items you can get the Cart that contains them.

Again, not sure if this is what you are asking for, and this is very quickly thrown together, but hopefully it helps.